# implement traversing record prev and next in sencha touchs

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

i am trying to create a panel where i can traverse the contact details from `phonegap` back and forth. so far i have successfully fetched the contact details from `phonegap` and storing it into an array and loading into `Ext.Store`. but how would i move to next record until the last one , as  there are so many records.

following is the image that i want to implement

[image]

Comment: Have you thought about using a carousel?  This is a perfect use case for that... http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.carousel.Carousel

Comment: yeah i have thought of it but the same issue , how would i traverse when user swaps ?

Comment: You mean "swipes"?  That is exactly what a carousel is, shows one page per record in a store, and moves to the next record when you swipe the screen...

Comment: but i have around 1000 records so if i push items into carousel dont you think so it would get little slower ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have everything you need to implement that contact view screen, only thing is you need to try.

You can even more optimize my code and don't copy past the code, just try to get idea from the code.

I can explain this code to you but you will understand better when you explore your own.

1) Basically, I created contactView panel with two butons and detail panel.

2) Detail panel have a panel for showing image and label for showing details.

3) I am controlling contact navigation using next and back button in controller.

**Model**

```
Ext.define('ContactApp.model.Contact', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            {name: 'name',  type: 'string'},
            {name: 'mobileNumber',   type: 'string'},
            {name: 'emailid', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'picture', type: 'string'}
        ]
    }
});
```

**Store**

```
Ext.define('ContactApp.store.Contact',{
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
    config : {
        model: "ContactApp.model.Contact",
        storeId : 'contact',
        data : [
            { name:'Anantha', mobileNumber:'9845633215', emailid: 'anantha@gmail.com', picture: 'resources/images/pic.jpg'},
            { name:'Viswa', mobileNumber:'9876543218', emailid: 'viswa@gmail.com', picture: 'resources/images/pic1.jpg'},
            { name:'Aravind', mobileNumber:'9878963213', emailid: 'aravind@gmail.com', picture: 'resources/images/pic2.jpg'},
            { name:'Ramesh', mobileNumber:'9877856321', emailid: 'ramesh@gmail.com', picture: 'resources/images/pic3.jpg'}
        ],
        autoLoad: true
    }
});
```

**View**

```
Ext.define('ContactApp.view.Contact',{
    extend : 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype : 'contactView',
    config : {
        items : [{
            xtype : 'titlebar',
            title : 'Contacts',
            items : [{
                ui: 'back', text: 'back', align : 'left', action: 'back', hidden: true
            },{
                ui: 'forward', text: 'next', align : 'right', action: 'next', hidden: true
            }]
        },{
            xtype : 'panel',
            itemId : 'contactDetail',
            layout : 'hbox',
            style : 'margin-left: 15%; margin-top:10%;',
            items : [{
                xtype : 'panel',
                itemId : 'picture',
                tpl : '<img src="{picture}" alt="picture" height= "64" width= "64">'
            },{
                xtype: 'spacer',
                width : 40
            },{
                xtype : 'label',
                itemId : 'details',
                tpl : '<div>{name}</div><div>{mobileNumber}</div><div>{emailid}</div>'
            }]
        }]
    },
    initialize : function() {
        this.fireEvent('onContactViewInit',this);
    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
Ext.define('ContactApp.controller.Contact', {
    extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config : {
        contactCount : 0,
        refs : {
            contactView : 'contactView',
            backBtn : 'button[action=back]',
            nextBtn : 'button[action=next]'
        },
        control : {
            contactView : {
                onContactViewInit : 'onContactViewInit'
            },
            backBtn : {
                tap : 'onBackTap'
            },
            nextBtn : {
                tap : 'onNextTap'
            }
        }
    },
    onContactViewInit : function(){
        var contactStore = Ext.getStore('contact');
        var count = contactStore.getCount();
        if(count){
            var index = this.getContactCount();
            var record = contactStore.getAt(index);
            this.setContact(record.getData());
            if(count>1)
                this.getNextBtn().show();
        }
    },
    setContact : function(data){
        var contactView = this.getContactView();
        var contactDetail = contactView.getComponent('contactDetail');
        contactDetail.getComponent('picture').setData(data);
        contactDetail.getComponent('details').setData(data);
    },
    onBackTap : function(){
        var contactStore = Ext.getStore('contact');
        var count = contactStore.getCount();
        var index = this.getContactCount();
        this.setContactCount(index-1);
        var record = contactStore.getAt(index-1);
        this.setContact(record.getData());
        this.getNextBtn().show();
        if(this.getContactCount() == 0)
            this.getBackBtn().hide();       
    },
    onNextTap : function(){
        var contactStore = Ext.getStore('contact');
        var count = contactStore.getCount();
        var index = this.getContactCount();
        this.setContactCount(index+1);
        var record = contactStore.getAt(index+1);
        this.setContact(record.getData());
        this.getBackBtn().show();
        if(this.getContactCount() == count-1)
            this.getNextBtn().hide();
    }
});
```

**Output**

We have four record, so

**Record 1**

[image]

**Record 2**

[image]

**Record 3**

[image]

**Record 4**

[image]

*That is what i do, i mean trying.*